# Does fixed:positioning work on mobile

Tags: css

I have a site with has a lot of fixed position elements. One big one is a full screen border created with divs around the whole screen

css

```
#top, #bottom, #left, #right {
  background: #a5ebff;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

It borders the entire page and I would like it to display on mobile screens the same as full screens.  However I have been told fixed elements act differently on mobile.

The site is not live so I can't tell if that is true nor do I have the range of devices which I would like it to appear on.

Comment: Why can't you try if the site is not live? You have a dev environment I may hope? Or something like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I meant I can't try on an actual phone version of internet browsers as it has been said they operate differently. I have not use things like jsfiddle to see cellphones

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the size of element which is `position:fixed`.

**Let me give you two examples**

1. A horizontal bar which is fixed at the top and has phone numbers on it.
2. Navigation Bar consisting around 8-10 menu items with submenus.

---

- `position:fixed` is good for Example #1 since the height of bar will be around 60-70px
- Whereas for Example #2 it is bad. Whenever a user opens the menu with so many menu items it takes the whole screen and user wont be able to navigate through other areas on the page because of `position:fixed`

I will be able to explain you with images after reaching home.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description. I am not worried about sizes, I have researched and have read multiple times that the fixed property doesn't work the same as on computer. Ex. the fixed element actually scrolls with the content like absolute.